# Unable to connect aws rds using Sailsjs adapters

Tags: mysql, sails.js, waterline, amazon-rds

I am able to access my aws rds mysql instance from mysql CLI. But same configuration is not working for sailsjs database adapter.

this is my ./config/env/production.js

```
connections: {
    mysqlServer: {
      host: "demo.c4a1v1iyi4x1.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com",
      user: "username",
      password: "password",
      database: "mydb",
    },
  },
```

I have modified my ./config/models.js to create tables

```
/**
 * Default model configuration
 * (sails.config.models)
 *
 * Unless you override them, the following properties will be included
 * in each of your models.
 *
 * For more info on Sails models, see:
 * http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM
 */

module.exports.models = {

  /***************************************************************************
  *                                                                          *
  * Your app's default connection. i.e. the name of one of your app's        *
  * connections (see `config/connections.js`)                                *
  *                                                                          *
  ***************************************************************************/
  connection: 'mysqlServer',

  /***************************************************************************
  *                                                                          *
  * How and whether Sails will attempt to automatically rebuild the          *
  * tables/collections/etc. in your schema.                                  *
  *                                                                          *
  * See http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/ORM/model-settings.html  *
  *                                                                          *
  * In a production environment (NODE_ENV==="production") Sails always uses  *
  * migrate:"safe" to protect inadvertent deletion of your data.             *
  * However development has a few other options for convenience:             *
  *                                                                          *
  * safe - never auto-migrate my database(s). I will do it myself (by hand)  *
  * alter - auto-migrate, but attempt to keep existing data (experimental)   *
  * drop - wipe/drop ALL my data and rebuild models every time I lift Sails  *
  *                                                                          *
  ***************************************************************************/
  migrate: 'alter',

};
```

Using above configurations , sails.js is unable to connect or create tables in aws rds instance.Can anyone help me with this . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us the error message.

Comment: Hey zabware, it doesn't give any error message. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Got the fault. Sails.Js  in production env  forces waterline to use 'migrate:safe' instead of 'alter' or 'drop'. So , any table creation was inhibited. Hence, I override the development config with production with 'migrate:alter' and tables were created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the fault. Sails.Js  in production env  forces waterline to use 'migrate:safe' instead of 'alter' or 'drop'. So , any table creation was inhibited. Hence, I override the development config with production with 'migrate:alter' and ran sails lift. Bingo! ALL TABLES WERE CREATED.

Sails was able to connect with rds but its own configuration was not allowing it to create table.